# Max number of auth-tokens that box can issue against a user at one time?

Tags: box-api

What is the maximum number of auth-tokens that Box can issue against an admin user of an enterprise at any point in time. I have a use-case where a number of my worker processes might need different auth-tokens(distributed nature of the problem). The number of these worker processes can be in hundreds. Will box be able to support that? I am using V2 API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box supports co-admins being setup.  Each of your admin users should really get setup as a co-admin, instead of trying to proxy all their work through a single admin-user.  That way the logging actually works and shows who did what.

Given that, I'm not sure it really matters how many times a user can login to an application.  If what you are trying to do is hard-code the auth-token for a single user, you can't really do that with OAuth2, since the auth-token only lasts for 1 hour, and the refresh token is only good for 1 use (or 60 days, whichever comes first).

If you're writing a distributed multi-threaded system, then you can have them all share an auth-token / refresh-token pair.   You'll want to have a way for all the workers/threads to coordinate on getting the new token/refresh-token pair

There's no limit to the number of applications a user can use.  Nor is there a limit to the number of times a user can use a single application.  So you might run the same app on your iPad, your iPhone, and your iPad mini, for example.

Comment: Making a user admin or co-admin is not in my control. I am not trying to hard-code auth-token...What I meant was that all of workers could have their own auth-refresh token pair. Is their a cap on the number of different auth-tokens that can exist against a user at one time?